# Why frameElement is null?

Tags: iframe, getattribute

I have problem with access to an iframe attribute from inside the iframe.

[image: HTML Structure]

```html
<ins><iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="728" height="90" style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    #document
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html><head><base target="_top"></head>
 <body border="0" margin="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
 <iframe id="ra_frame" src="//banners.com/index.html" link="URL" style="width:728px!important; height:90px!important" ;="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
 </body></html>
</iframe></ins>
```

When I call frameElement iside the second iframe I get null.

```js
window.frameElement.getAttribute("link"); //Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

[image: Console snapeshot]

How can I get link attribute from inside the second iframe?

**upd**
It's code from Revive Adserver, this iframes loading via JS. If load it in iframe manually all works fine.

**upd** One solution is add needed parameters to src get parameter.

Comment: Post some code so we can understand the problem. Images are acceptable if: **1.** There is code and the images are secondary source. **2.** If they are actually viewable. When I clicked that blurry ness, I was expecting the image zoom in like all image embeds on SO,

Comment: @zer00ne I added code. Blurried are only links.